# Multi part identifier could not be found using a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which populates a temporary table:

```
with CTE as
(
select a.accountid as 'myid',
       a.new_mprnnumber, 
       a.new_customernumber,
       b.*, 
       row_number() 
         over (partition by new_customernumber -- add additional partitions as you would group bys
               order by billingPeriodEndDate desc) as r_ord 
from [CRM].[crm4_MSCRM].[dbo].[AccountExtensionBase] a
inner join bill  b
  on a.new_mprnnumber = b.MPRN
where new_accountstage = 7
and new_accounttype = 2 
)
select *
into #tempCTE
from CTE
where r_ord = 1
```

After gathering the information in the temporary table I want to iterate through each record and update the main table using the accountid but using the following statement:

```
update [CRM].[crm4_MSCRM].[dbo].[AccountExtensionBase]
set new_invoicenumber = invoicenumber
where accountid = #tempCTE.myid
```

I am getting the error that the multi part identifier could not be bound, any idea on what is causing this issue?

Comment: Can you execute just select from CTE?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to iterate through the records? THat is something that should almost never be done in a database. You have already identified the most recent record in the CTE.

Comment: Because it was taking so long I was just checking it was doing the same thing, it took 13:10 minutes to update 4163 accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bring in the temporary table:

```
update aeb
    set new_invoicenumber = t.invoicenumber
    from [CRM].[crm4_MSCRM].[dbo].[AccountExtensionBase] aeb join
         #tempCTE t
         on aeb.accountid = t.myid;
```

As a note, you don't need a temporary table.  You can just do:

```
with tempCTE as ( . . . )
update aeb
    set new_invoicenumber = t.invoicenumber
    from [CRM].[crm4_MSCRM].[dbo].[AccountExtensionBase] aeb join
         tempCTE t
         on aeb.accountid = t.myid
    where tempCTE.r_ord = 1
```

Comment: do i leave my r_ord = 1 statement in there?

Comment: I only want to update the invoice number with the latest invoice, The list should return to me the accountid which I then wanted to use as the key for updating

Comment: YEs put  r_ord = 1 in as a where clause in the update statement.